# TFS2012 Access to VSPROPS file denied

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So I am trying to run a build on VS2012 paired with TFS2012. I have made some modifications to the build template being used, but none that should be troublesome. My problem comes around when I try to execute the build, the build summary gives me the following error:

Exception Message: Access to the path 'C:\AiDevelopment\AiFramework\toolbox\Accelitec.Utility\Accelitec.Utility.csproj.vsprops' is denied. (type UnauthorizedAccessException)

Now normally I would take this as a permissions issue, however I go to try and find this contentious little file, and it doesn't exist! (At least not in the path specified). Sooooo... what is going on? How can my build report that it is denied access to a file that isn't there? How can I fix it?

Update: I have found the file, it is on the build server. This server has VS2008 installed on it for other uses, which makes me think that VS2008 is interfering with the build somehow, seeing as .vsprops files are used only in VS2008 and older. Why would my VS2012 builds be creating a .vsprops file?